# How to hide variables in package.json

Tags: reactjs, package.json

I have the following scripts in my package.json file

```
"docker-build": "docker build -t mouchin/my-image-name .",
    "docker-push": "docker push mouchin/my-image-name:latest",
    "deploy-server": "ssh root@myserverip 'docker pull mouchin/my-image-name:latest'",
    "deploy": "npm run docker-build && npm run docker-push && npm run deploy-server"
```

Problem is that i want to hide
`mouchin/my-image-name` and  `root@myserverip`

Using some sort of env, maybe saving my variables in .env.prod  , but i dont know if i can read the variables saved there directly into package.json

Comment: You could write your own small script to read args from cli or read a .env file thats ignored in version control.

Answer (score 0):

You can use environment variables in your rpm scripts just as you would if you execute the command on the command line (for example $SSH_HOST). However those variables will need to be set directly in the shell that executes the nom script.

Now in order to get the environment variables from an env file loaded, you have to do so manually. For example using a snippet like this:

```
if [ ! -f .env ]
then
export $(cat .env | xargs)
fi
```

[Source](https://gist.github.com/mihow/9c7f559807069a03e302605691f85572)

To execute this before any other script, you could use the built-in [lifecylce scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/scripts#life-cycle-scripts) of npm.

Perhaps, you also want to change the snippet code to load one or the other `.env` file in case you have one for production and one for development. You will probably be able to use the environment variable `NODE_ENV` for this, as it is used in most setups, however this last step really depends on your build setup.